# Poco::Dynamic::Var created empty object by operator []

Tags: c++, json, c++11, c++14, poco-libraries

I try to check the parameter is existing in Poco::Dynamic::Var.
But after checking I found that source object is changed. Appeared a new parameter, which I checked.

**Problem:**

How to check the presence of a parameter in an Poco::Dynamic::Var without modifying the source object.

**Code example:**

```
void checkParamInConfig(Poco::Dynamic::Var &conf) {
    std::cout << "before:" << conf.toString() << std::endl;

    // new key problem
    if (conf["Configuration"]["NewParam"].isEmpty()) {
        std::cout<<"NewParam not found"<<std::endl;
    }
    
    std::cout << "after:" << conf.toString() << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
before:{ "Configuration" : { "Param1" : true, "Param2" : true, "Param3" : true } }
NewParam not found
after:{ "Configuration" : { "NewParam" : null, "Param1" : true, "Param2" : true, "Param3" : true } }
```

Comment: I don't know much about pco, but a simple guess, you should have used the `Poco::Dynamic::Var::find()` function there instead: `Poco::Dynamic::Var::operator[][]...`

Comment: Poco::Dynamic::Var doesn't have find() function

Answer (score 0):

`Poco::Dynamic::Var` does not have a `find()` function, but `Poco::Dynamic::Struct` does have `find()` and `contains()`.

You need to extract the `Struct` value out of the `Var` like so:

```cpp
void checkParamInConfig(Poco::Dynamic::Var &conf)
{
    std::cout << "before:" << conf.toString() << std::endl;

    auto params = conf["Configuration"];
    if (params.isStruct())
    {
        auto p = params.extract<Poco::Dynamic::Struct<std::string>>();
        if (!p.contains("NewParam"))
        {
            std::cout << "NewParam not found" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << "after:" << conf.toString() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
before:{ "Configuration" : { "Param1" : true, "Param2" : true, "Param3" : true } }
NewParam not found
after:{ "Configuration" : { "Param1" : true, "Param2" : true, "Param3" : true } }
```